# Need to modify the regex for validating the UK Phone

Tags: php, regex, validation, phone-number

I have a php validation of the UK phone number, inputed by potential clients in my form.
It looks like this:

```
function phoneUK(phone){
    var regex = /^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?)|(?:\(?0))(?:\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?\s?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}\s?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?\s?\d{4,5})$/i;
    return regex.test(phone);
}
```

The problem is that in this form it only allows phone numbers with a 0 in front followed by ten digits (`0XXXX XXXXXX`) and since recently there are also legitimate phone numbers with eleven digits after the leading zero.

How to alter the code so these type of phone numbers are allowed?

Comment: I think the preg_match PHP command is ideal for handling more anomalies while still finding patterns. The format is like this: preg_match($validPattern, $patternUnsure)  where $validPattern is the 10 digits.  $patternUnsure is the 10 to 11 digits that may or may not start with a 0.

Comment: There you go.
`^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?)|(?:\(?0))(?:\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?\s?(?:\d{5,6}|\d{3}\s?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?\s?\d{4,5})`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Vishwa! Unfortunately the solution you proposed did not work. I'm still restrained to only input a phone number with 10 digits after the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function phoneUK(phone){
    var regex = /^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?)|(?:\(?0))(?:\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}|\d{2}\)?\s?\d{5}\s?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{3}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?\s?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}\s?\d{3}|\d{4}\s?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?\s?\d{4,5}|\d{5,6}\)?\s?\d{4,6})$/i;
    return regex.test(phone);
}
```

Hope this helps.